# How should I configure the Oracle HTTP server to handle PL/SQL page requests?

Tags: oracle, plsql, weblogic

I am wanting to build an Oracle OFM development environment on Windows 7 (64-bit) to migrate over an existing java/struts and PL/SQL application from OAS10G.  So far I have installed the Oracle Database product (), Java 7, and WebLogic Server (10.3.6 = wls1036_generic).

Have I installed everything I need as far as OFM is concerned?  I can't see how to configure the oracle http server to handle PL/SQL page requests.  I spotted on post that said this can be done through the Oracle Fusion Middleware Control - which should be found at my-domain:7001/em, but that tool doesn't seem to be found.  I only seem to have the WebLogic Server Console (my-domain:7001/console) which has lots of tabs and options but I don't see anything that lets me configure the ohs (Oracle Http Server).  Does the Oracle Http Server (ohs) even get installed as part of the WebLogic installation?

Thanks for any help.  Oracle product installations confuse me.

Answer (score 1):

The OHS is confusing, as it hard to understand if you need a middle tier (OFM) or not.

And really you don't need a full OFM install, you just need the Web Tier.

In 11g:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/webtier/downloads/index-jsp-156711.html

In 12 (I have not yet installed this) the download is:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/index-091236.html

After installing, I manually modify the dad.conf file to set up the DADs.

Keep in mind that using Oracle Http Server on the same machine as the database does not require a OFM license.  If you install it on another machine, you do need to pay it.

The other thing you can do is install the Oracle Apex Listener.  This is actually better than OHS because it can handle true REST request (where as OHS can only handle application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data).

Download:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex-listener/overview/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnpt

I've installed this using Glassfish as a middle tier, and it works well. The Apex Listener does not require another licenses and can be installed anywhere...

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I just figured out yesterday that I needed to install the Web Tier component as well and then associate an instance with the WebLogic domain I created.  I haven't quite finished the setup, but I am now able to launch the Fusion Middleware Control, and am about ready to create my web instance.  So I am hoping I am on the road to success now.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you did? I'm currently trying to figure out the question above. I've got the Web Tier component but I'm not sure how to connect my PL/SQL, my htlm/css, and my Oracle HTTP Web Server all together. I'd love any guidance you can provide. @Kent